# Apache2 redirect path to PHP script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wish to redirect all calls of:

```
www.mydomain.com/api
```

To

```
www.mydomain.com/api.php
```

In other instances there may be sub paths that must be translated to query strings:

```
www.mydomain.com/api/id/3def
```

Must become:

```
www.mydomain.com/api?id=3def
```

I tried using Rewrite Rule in .htaccess file but I could not get them to work. The most basic case of redirecting /api to /api.php is not working.

Comment: What in you `.htaccess`?

Comment: Do you already have some rules in your htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines should do:

```
RewriteRule ^/?api/([^/]+)/(.*)   /api.php?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?api/?$             /api.php [L]
```

If you need an explanation, have a read of: [URL Aliasing, Redirection, Rewriting and Reverse Proxying using Apache HTTPD](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/4043/URL-Aliasing-Redirection-Rewriting-and-Reverse-Proxying-using-Apache-HTTPD.html?cfr=60)